# Retrieve data from model to controller

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

In User model data is print if I do echo $data. My question is how retrieve same data in user controller, I tried to do , but didn't work.

user.php(model)

```
function display_children($parent, $level) 
       {  
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT title FROM tree '.'WHERE parent="'.$parent.'"');

     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
             {  
                   $data =  str_repeat('  ',$level).$row['title']."\n";

                   // echo $data  if i remove comment it display all data 

                   // i m getting all data on this variable $data 

                   $this->display_children($row['title'], $level+1);
             }
    }
```

users_controller.php

```
public function admin_mlm($id){

     pr($this->User->display_children('Food',0));   // function argument work but no data printed here
}
```

Comment: Is there some data for level = 0 in the DB?

Comment: i pass argument from user controller, my data display properly in model , i have problem how to retrieve same data in controller

Comment: I wonder why you are not using the wrapper class (datasource) for simple tasks as this. thats one of the main advantages of a powerful framework after all.

Comment: @mark , thank for reply,could u you explain more to short out that problem

Comment: `$this->find('all', array('fields'=>array('title'), 'conditions'=>array('parent'=>$parent)));`

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the [CakePHP 1.3 Conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/901/CakePHP-Conventions) in your app, you wouldn't have to use the 'mysql_query()' and 'mysql_fetch_array()' PHP functions in a CakePHP based app.

This is why it is a framework - It provides another abstraction layer to a Application.

So if you have followed the conventions in your Controller you can do:

```
$this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('id' => $user_id)));
```

You can supply almost what ever as a condition, or a order etc.
Check out the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1017/Retrieving-Your-Data).

Also there is the special ['threaded' Model::find() type](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1018/find#find-threaded-1023). It returns a nested array. Check it out! ;)

Comment: thats what I was thinking... even for custom sql statements he should be using the datasource (and query method). but in this simple case one really should use find() :)

Comment: wht about while loop condition, i mean to say how to use while loop

Comment: I just edited my answer to include, something that I had missed. Check the Model::find('threaded') out. :)